# Forecast methodology for geographic variables that are somewhat related

Tags: python, scikit-learn, time-series, forecasting, forecast

I'm creating time series forecasts for different geographies and wanted an expert opinion on how I can take into account geographic relationship to improve my model. Is there an algorithm that's suitable for this usecase?
Let me know if you need more context

Comment: Please help me understand the use-case here. This is what I understood from your question; you are building a `time-series` forecasting model e.g. `daily-temperature` forecast for city A, B, and C; and you want to use geographic relationship. What does the `geographic relationship` implies?

Comment: @DataFramed That's correct, the `geographic relationship` would implies that these regions are in close proximity and hence can have similar trends. Hope this helps!